# Django Admin: How to add foreign key relational other integer field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I want to add data from django admin. I have 3 models Employee, OverTime and Pay.

Here are my models:

```
class OverTime(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_hour = models.IntegerField()
    overtime_amount = models.IntegerField() #per hour
    total_amount = models.IntegerField(editable=False)

class Pay(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    month = models.CharField(max_length=15) 
    salary = models.IntegerField()
    overtime = models.ForeignKey(OverTime,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_amount = models.IntegerField(editable=False)
```

When I create payroll data in django-admin, `total_amount` value should be shown in `overtime`.
[image]

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
class OverTime(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_hour = models.IntegerField()
    overtime_amount = models.IntegerField() #per hour
    total_amount = models.IntegerField(editable=False)
    **def __str__(self):
        return self.total_amount**
```

save that under OverTime model

Comment: total_amount is an IntegerField, How can it work?